# I need assistance with my intro to Java assignment

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I have successfully compiled this java program (which generates 100 random numbers between 0 and 25, puts them in an array, and sorts them into two different arrays based on whether each is even or odd), although it does not run. I suspect I have made a mistake with one of the while loops, although I don't know for sure. Also, I struggled to get the code in properly formatted in the question, so the tabs are somewhat off, but it is still mostly legible. Here is the .java text:

```
public class Assignment8
{
    public static void main( String [] args )
    {
        int storage [] = new int[100];
        int j = 0;  

        while ( storage.length < 100 )  {
            int testVariable = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * ((25 - 0) + 1));
            storage[j] = testVariable;
            j++;
        }

        int oddArray[] = OddNumbers( storage );
        int evenArray[] = EvenNumbers( storage );
        int currentNumber = 0;

        System.out.println( "The odd numbers are: " + "\n" );

        while ( currentNumber <= 99 ) {
            System.out.println( oddArray[currentNumber] + "\n" );
            currentNumber++;
        }

        System.out.println( "\n" + "The even numbers are: " + "\n" );
        currentNumber = 0;

        while ( currentNumber <= 99 ) {
            System.out.println( evenArray[currentNumber] + "\n" );
            currentNumber++;
        }
    }

    public static int[] OddNumbers( int storage[] )
    {
        int currentNumber = 0;
        int currentValue = storage[currentNumber];
        int oddArray[] = new int[100];

        while ( currentNumber <= 99 ) {
            if ( storage[currentNumber] % 2 != 0 ) {
                oddArray[currentNumber] = currentValue;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

            currentNumber++;        
        }

        return oddArray;
    }

    public static int[] EvenNumbers( int storage[] )
    {
        int currentNumber = 0;
        int currentValue = storage[currentNumber];
        int evenArray[] = new int[100];

        while ( currentNumber <= 99 ) {
            if ( storage[currentNumber] % 2 == 0 ) {
                evenArray[currentNumber] = currentValue;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

            currentNumber++;        
        }

        return evenArray;
     }
}
```

Comment: The place to start is to step through the code one line at a time in your IDE debugger.  Have you done that yet?  If so, tell us what you found that you don't understand.

Comment: Please include sample output or the error.

Comment: This is beside the point, but why write `25 - 0` instead of `25`

Comment: I suggest you use your IDE to a) format your code, b) help you debug it. BTW You can write this in about 5 lines of code.

Comment: https://ideone.com/mfDWwT

Answer (score 2):

`storage.length` does not change throughout the program's execution, as the array is already allocated. You first `while` loop is thus wrong, as 100 is not less than 100, it will never execute. Instead, you could use a simple `for` loop:

```
for (int j  = 0; j < storage.length; ++j) {
    int testVariable = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * ((25 - 0) + 1));
    storage[j] = testVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> although it does not run

Yes it does. It's just that the execution can get stuck in the infinite loops in the `OddNumbers` and `EvenNumbers` methods.
Take a closer look at this:

> ```
> while ( currentNumber <= 99 ) {
>     if ( storage[currentNumber] % 2 != 0 ) {
>         oddArray[currentNumber] = currentValue;
>     }
>     else {
>         continue;
>     }
> ```

The problem is that when `storage[currentNumber]` is even,
the program executes the `else` branch with the `continue` statement,
and since `currentNumber` hasn't changed, and so `storage[currentNumber]` hasn't changed either, it's still even, and the `else` branch will be executed again, and again, and again, forever. `EvenNumber` has the same problem too.

Here's a fix for `OddNumbers`:

```
public static int[] OddNumbers(int[] storage) {
    int[] oddArray = new int[storage.length];

    int oddIndex = 0;
    for (int num : storage) {
        if (num % 2 != 0) {
            oddArray[oddIndex++] = num;
        }
    }

    return Arrays.copyOf(oddArray, oddIndex);
}
```

An extra touch I did in this method is the `Arrays.copyOf` call,
chopping off the excess elements of the array that would be otherwise 0.

Then when you print the content of this array in `main`, write like this:

```
System.out.println("The odd numbers are: " + "\n");

for (int num : oddArray) {
    System.out.println(num);
}
```

Follow the same pattern to fix `EvenNumbers`.

As @Mureinik pointed out,
the loop in `main` populating `storage` is also broken.
And you have several other coding issues,
for example the random number generation is particularly ugly and using an obsolete technique.

The complete improved implementation:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Assignment8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int[] storage = new int[100];    
        for (int i = 0; i < storage.length; i++) {
            storage[i] = random.nextInt(25);
        }

        System.out.println("The odd numbers are: " + "\n");

        int oddArray[] = OddNumbers(storage);
        for (int num : oddArray) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }

        System.out.println("\n" + "The even numbers are: " + "\n");

        int evenArray[] = EvenNumbers(storage);
        for (int num : evenArray) {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }

    public static int[] OddNumbers(int[] storage) {
        int index = 0;
        int[] result = new int[storage.length];

        for (int num : storage) {
            if (num % 2 != 0) {
                result[index++] = num;
            }
        }

        return Arrays.copyOf(result, index);
    }

    public static int[] EvenNumbers(int storage[]) {
        int index = 0;
        int[] result = new int[storage.length];

        for (int num : storage) {
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
                result[index++] = num;
            }
        }

        return Arrays.copyOf(result, index);
    }
}
```